# Unset variable by its name given as a string

Tags: downvalues, assignment

Unlike the function [Clear](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clear.html), the function [Unset](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unset.html) does not work for string patterns. Given the name of a variable as a string, how can you unset the corresponding variable? Example:

Given:

```
x = 10;
```

trying to unset later:

```
Unset[Symbol["x"]]
```

results in

```
Unset::write: Tag Symbol in Symbol[x] is Protected. >>
```

Using `With`:

```
With[{var = Symbol["x"]}, Unset[var]]
```

results in

```
Unset::usraw: Cannot unset raw object 10. >>
```

Note that `Clear["x"]` is not an option, because it also removes all `DownValues` associated with `x`.

Comment: Dumb solution: `ToExpression["Unset[" <> "x" <> "]"]`.

Comment: `ToExpression@MakeBoxes[RawBoxes["x"] =.]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the third argument of `ToExpression` to do this in a structured way:

```
ToExpression["x", InputForm, Unset]
```

Comment: That's a tricky solution! Thanks.

Comment: +1. I remember that you have a long history of using this construct, which I also use often. @sakra An alternative: `Unset @@ ToHeldExpression["x"]`

Comment: Yes, it's useful when trying to do something with some symbols I get from `Names["...*"]`.  The usual form one ends up with is `ToExpression["x", InputForm, Function[expr, ..., {HoldAll}]]`, which is rather cumbersome.  I did not know about `ToHeldExpression`.  It might make some things simpler.

Comment: @Szabolcs `ToHeldExpression` is deprecated and undocumented, but I am sure it will stay.

Comment: As noted [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/functions/ToHeldExpression), `ToHeldExpression[]` was deprecated in version three. Still, it remains in the kernel, much like that other function `Release[]`...

Comment: @Szabolcs I was using `f @ ToExpression["x", InputForm, Unevaluated]` but your method from the comment has less limitations, thanks.